# Android - What is the best way to maintain multiple images?

Tags: android, resources, android-image

During my game loop I am constantly loading images using

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.objectx);
```

Most of the time I'm calling images that have already been decoded earlier. Am I slowing down execution by decoding the resource every time?
Is it better to store every image into a Map (or Dictionary) at the beginning of the program? If so, how do you get the resource IDs for all images in the drawable folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is it better to store every image into a Map (or Dictionary) at the beginning of the program?

Yeah... it's much better. Or you can store them as soon as you need them; is not necessary to store them all at the beginning.

> > If so, how do you get the resource IDs for all images in the drawable folder?

The drawable folder does not contains images only; it also have xml resources. So that's not the way to go.

Comment: Okay, so as I need an image I'll check if it exists in the map. If it doesn't then I'll decode it and add it. Thanks.